# How do you return piped data from a module?

Tags: javascript, module, stream, pipe

I have a filter function that runs a data stream through a pipe of several other filters.
How do I return the data at the end of the pipe?

```
// takes a stream and returns a stream
function fixdata(data_in) {
    data_in
    .pipe(fix_data_types)
    .pipe(choose_columns)
    .pipe(filter_bad_data)
    .pipe( return? ); 
}
module.exports = fixdata;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pipe` function returns the data so the next function can use it. So all you need is to return it:

```
function fixdata(data_in) {
  return data_in
    .pipe(fix_data_types)
    .pipe(choose_columns)
    .pipe(filter_bad_data); 
}
```